# Custom GroundOverlay in Google Map

Tags: android

[image]

I am trying to show a groudoverlay like this image on map in android. Please suggest me how can I do that.

Latlng latlng = new LatLng(...);

```
GroundOverlayOptions overlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
       .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.layout.custom_layout)
       .position(latlng , 0f, 0f); 
 map.addGroundOverlay(overlay);
```

Comment: Did you try anything by yourself? Where is the exact difficulty?

Comment: yes! I can add only image but tried to add a view after inflating it from a custom layout. But it says it only can add drawable resources. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Post your code - it will make it much easier for people to comment and suggest solutions.